# React no me deja hacer scroll hacía abajo

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

He creado un array de cartas que se renderiza como quería el problema que tengo es que aunque el resto de componentes se renderizan también y se muestran en la consola y en la estructura de la página, estos aparecen más abajo y no me deja hacer scroll hacia ellos, he intentado usar `ScrollView` pero visto como funciona he entendido que no sirve para lo que quiero hacer.

Adjunto código

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Home.css';

// Estructura de los datos en React
export default class FetchEquipo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        equipos: []
    };

    // Inicio de la petición asincrona a la API
    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Equipos/?format=json";
        // Await de la función para esperar a la respuesta asincrona y obtener los datos
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = await response.data;
        // Cambio del estado de los datos porque llegado aquí ya se han recibido
        this.setState({ equipos: data, loading: false });

    }

    render() {
        // Mostrará un escenario dependiendo de si estan o no cargados los datos
        if (this.state.loading === true) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else if (!this.state.equipos.length === null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>No se encontraron datos de los equipos</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            // Mapeo del array de equipos por cada uno de los equipos
            const equiposJSx = [];
            this.state.equipos.forEach(equipo => {
                equiposJSx.push(
                    // Componente raíz del grupo al que se le pasa una key unica en este caso ek nombre del equipo
                    <div className='card-container' key={equipo.Equipo}>
                        <div className='image-container'>
                            <img src={equipo.Equipo}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className='card-content'>
                            <div className='card-title'>
                                <h3>{equipo.Equipo}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className='card-body'>
                                <p>Valor total: {equipo.ValorTotal}</p>
                                <p>Valor Medio: {equipo.ValorMedio}</p>
                                <p>Jugadores: {equipo.Jugadores}</p>
                                <p>Edad media: {equipo.EdadMedia}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            });

            return (
                    <div className="row">
                        {equiposJSx}
                    </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Adjunto imagen del problema
[image: Adjunto imagen del problema]

Como veis en la imagen no se muestra ninguna scrollbar ni nada, he probado usando `flatlist` pero tampoco se adapata a lo que quiero que es poder hacer scroll hacía abajo para así poder ver el resto de componentes

**Edit 1**:
En el css tengo el overflow puesto en hidden

```
.card-container{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: ease-in;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.card-container:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.image-container img{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}
.card-content{
    margin: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.9rem;
}
h3, p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.card-title{
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu css? Posiblemente la propiedad `overflow` es la que comúnmente maneja la posibilad de scrollear

Comment: Tienes los estilos de la clase `App`? ponle `overflow: scroll` y debiése funcionar

Comment: Lo tengo puesto en scroll en la app pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la [documentación de overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container
> must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space
> set to nowrap.

Tratando de emular el caso que tienes (sin definir la propiedad `height`):

```css
.card-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: ease-in;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.image-container {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Nota como el `scrollbar` del `div` contendor no funciona, en cambio con la propiedad `height` definida, como especifica la documentación:

```css
.card-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: ease-in;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.image-container {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

En tu caso tendrías que envolver tus elementos con el `div` que tenga el `overflow:scroll` y una altura definida por medio de `height`.